# Using Fody Costura with Entity Framework Core migrations

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core

My WPF program is using Entity Framewok Core 3.1.1 (code-first) with a SQLite database. If the database file does not exist on startup, the program calls `context.Database.Migrate()` to create one. Works great.

When I added Costura.Fody (using NuGet), that huge collection of DLLs disappeared and the program still works - until it needs to create a new database file. Then the `Migrate()` function fails with an error:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception - The path is not of a legal form.

I have a similar issue if I try to use the Package Manager Console to add a migration manually - I get

> Your startup project doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Removing the Fody Costura package causes everything to start working again. I haven't found anything on SO or elsewhere that references this issue, and Fody seems to be very popular, so I must be doing something dumb, but I don't know where to look.

Does anyone know how to get Fody Costura and EF Core migrations to coexist?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite doesn't do well as an embedded resourse without a bit of tweaking. I know this is a common issue with Unit Tests as well when using Costura.Fody as [specified in the docs](https://github.com/Fody/Costura#unit-testing).

A simple adjustment of the Weavers xml should fix the issue though. Have a look at [Embedding Sqlite Files](https://old.idmedia.no/general/including-sqlite-interop-dll-into-your-c-project/).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Tronald for putting me on the right track.  For anyone else who comes across this, for me the trick was to exclude all the SQLitePCLRaw DLLs like this:

```
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <Costura >
    <ExcludeAssemblies>
      SQLitePCLRaw.*
    </ExcludeAssemblies>
  </Costura>
</Weavers>
```

Answer (score 0):

ClarkG, oh my god... I am trying to solve it at least 15 hours of clear time.
Thank you!

Your solution works on Migrate(), but doesn't work on add-migration xxx
It s a little problem... I just uninstall fody every time when I create a new migration. And then install it again.

If I don't uninstall Fody then add-migration writes:

> Your startup project 'InstaGTO' doesn't reference
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the
>   Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is
>   correct, install the package, and try again.