# Using EF Core 3.1 SQLite database in .NET 4.7.2 class library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have included package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` (latest 3.1.x version) in a .NET 4.7.2 Project.
This is the `OnConfiguring` Method of my `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    options.UseSqlite($@"Data Source=D:\MyDb.db");
}
```

I reference the class library from another .NET 4.7.2 project.

Whenever I try to read from, write to or create the database (like `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();`), I get the following `TypeInitializationException` on `SqliteConnection` constructor with the following InnerException:

Message: `The path has an invalid format`

StackTrace:

```
at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.InternalGetDirectoryName(String path)
   at SQLitePCL.NativeLibrary.MakePossibilitiesFor(String basename, Assembly assy, Int32 flags, LibSuffix suffix)
   at SQLitePCL.NativeLibrary.MyLoad(String basename, Assembly assy, Int32 flags, Action`1 log)
   at SQLitePCL.NativeLibrary.Load(String libraryName, Assembly assy, Int32 flags)
   at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.MakeDynamic(String name, Int32 flags)
   at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.DoDynamic_cdecl(String name, Int32 flags)
   at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init()
```

I guess path is related to my ConnectionString but I don't see what's wrong with it.

For testing purposes I have created a .NET 5 Project and refereced the 4.7.2 class library from there. If I call `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` In this project, it works as expected and the database is created.

So I guess it is an issues regarding the mix of .NET 4.7.2 and EF Core. But according to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/miscellaneous/platforms) EF Core 3.1 should work fine with .NET 4.7.2

Maybe something with the SQLite Adapter of EF Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TypeInitializationException`  mislead me in the wrong direction. In the end, it was a problem with the `Costura.Fody` package I'm using in the .NET 4.7.2 Project to bundle all DLLs into one *.exe file.

Seems this does not work well with SQLite Libraries. For whatever reason the `SQLitePCLRaw.*.dll` files were not included which resulted in the described `TypeInitializationException`. Usually, one would get a `FileNotFoundException` if a DLL is not included.

See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61418699/2424272) on a similar question that unfortunately I only found after I had posted my question here.